# Laws of equivalence needed to prove $\;q \leftrightarrow (¬p ∨ ¬q) ≡ (¬p ∧ q)\;?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm not sure which laws should be applied and how I can tell for myself how to discern which laws I should use - any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I can understand where you're coming from, but the question asks me to show how the outcome of (q ⇔ (¬p ∨ ¬q)) is logically equivalent to (¬p ∧ q) - for instance using a truth table, q ⇔ (¬p ∨ ¬q) results in F F T F (presuming p is T T F F and q is T F T F). Similarly, (¬p ∧ q) results in F F T F, demonstrating that they are equivalent. I'm just not sure which laws I should state demonstrate this.

If I'm still incorrect and the above makes no sense, I'll likely need to ask my tutor at university! Haha

Thanks,

Comment: A truth table is probably faster than symbolic manipulation here, since a lot of the manipulation here amounts to $q \wedge \neg q \equiv \bot$ and similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} q\iff (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) &\equiv [q \rightarrow (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)] \land [(\lnot p \lor \lnot q ) \rightarrow q]\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot q \lor \lnot p\lor \lnot q) \land [\lnot(p \land q) \rightarrow q)]\\ \\
& \equiv (\lnot q \lor \lnot p) \land [(p \land q) \lor q]\\ \\
&\equiv \lnot (q \land p) \land [(p \land q) \lor q]\\ \\
& \equiv [\lnot(q \land p) \land (p \land q)] \lor [\lnot (q \land p) \land q]\\ \\
&\equiv \lnot (q \land p) \land q\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot q \lor \lnot p) \land q\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot q \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)\\ \\
&\equiv \lnot p \land q
\end{align}$$

Comment: I appreciate your detailed working, but I was actually hoping for any logical laws I can apply to this (e.g. from this list http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/gordon.pace/Teaching/DiscreteMaths/Laws.pdf)

Comment: @AndrewWhiskin - now it is more easy to answer .... :) For example, the final step is derived according to the laws $(¬q∧q) \equiv false$ and $(false \lor A) \equiv A$. You can easily supply the above proof with the references to the laws used.

Comment: Part of your task is to be able to apply laws, but also identify the laws being used. I've applied some laws you can use; you need to try to identify them. To begin with, I applied one definition of the biconditional: $a \iff b \equiv (a\rightarrow b) \land (b \rightarrow a).$ I also use the definition of implication: $a \rightarrow b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$. You need the distributive law, as well as knowing what allows you to conclude $a \land \lnot a = F$. Etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, amWhy, Mauro & Ian :)